# VS2013 MVC Debug: Chrome Doesn't Reflect Updated File

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, google-chrome, visual-studio-2013, javascript-debugger

I was busily debugging an MVC4 app, written in C# under VS2013, using the Chrome debugger. Everything was working fine... until suddenly Chrome stopped reflecting updates to the view I was editing.

In other words, I'd change code in the view in VS2013 (while the server was running), flip over to Chrome, hit reload (or event Ctrl-F5)...and my changes were ignored.

I tried clearing the Chrome cache. No joy.

I tried rebooting the machine. No joy.

What the heck is going on? Feels like there's a cached version of the file someplace which didn't get deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read the post below:

```
http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link
```

The Browser Link controls are located in the dropdown with the circular arrow icon. The arrow icon is the Refresh button.

I have not tried this but according to the post, the Refresh button would reload your changes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanx! I was able to make the problem go away by deleting every temporary file for the site and clearing everything -- not just the cache -- from Chrome for the last 24 hours. So I can't test your idea, but I'm definitely going to keep it in mind for the next time.

Comment: Beaucoup thanx!! The problem occurred again, and your solution was spot on!